# How to check if a sentence begins with a non-english word in python?

Tags: python, list, nltk

I have tried the following code to check if the sentence has non-english words.But I want to check if the beginning of the sentence itself has the non-english word and hence remove that entire sentence. I have also tried the startswith() method along with the isalpha() method but didn't work.

So if there are a list of non-english and english sentences I want to recognize the non-english ones and remove them from the list. Please help me resolve this.

```
import nltk
#nltk.download('words')
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

sent = "Какую выберешь ты? abcd12 すべてのように置いてみましょう . Выложи фото с продукцией или боржоми и получи за это деньги. За подробностями пиши в директ."
wr=[]
for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent):
    #print(w)
    if(w.isalpha()==True):
        wr.append(w)

print(wr)
```

Comment: An "English word" is very hard to define. :-)  咖啡 (kā fēi), for example, is an English word transliterated into Chinese characters. Is that an English word?

Comment: Some ideas for how to proceed: If you have sentences, perhaps you can segment the sentence and perform per-sentence langid. It won't be perfect, but nothing will be. Another idea would be to eliminate tokens which are written in non-Latin scripts.

Comment: I was referring to commonly used english words, not transliterated words.

Comment: What about résumé? My point is words don't "fall" into languages like you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: @erip Yes, but it does come from old french. Nowadays, we usually write those kind of words without the accents, and if with the accents, it is not wrong to call it a different language too.

Comment: This is a linguistics philosophy question that I'm quite confident is off-topic, but to say "it's not wrong to call it a different language" is exactly my point - a word can be simultaneously a French word and an English word. Nothing belongs to a single language, which is why we group language families when discussing phenomena in groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enchant library to access a dictionary:

```
import enchant

dict = enchant.Dict('en_US')

sent = "Какую выберешь ты? abcd12 すべてのように置いてみましょう . Выложи фото с продукцией или боржоми и получи за это деньги. За подробностями пиши в директ."
new_sent = ''

for sentence in sent.split('.'):
    if dict.check(sentence.split(' ')[0]):
        print(sentence)
```

Comment: Hi, but the above code gave a valueerror --"ValueError: can't check spelling of empty string".

Comment: This is because of the whitespace after the dot. You can either split the dots and the whitespaces by using sent.split('. ') or you can just remove any whitespaces in a word by doing `sentence.split(' ')[0].replace(' ', '')`